# JAVASCRIPT - Função não carrega

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite, o problema é o seguinte:

Estou fazendo um extensão para o chrome ela funciona da seguinte forma:

assim que a página carrega, insere imagens de emoticons para quando alguém clicar em cima delas, carregar os emoticons na textarea. Só que acontece um erro da seguinte forma:

Quando a extensão carrega aparece os emoticons e eu clico neles para adicionar na textarea, no console aparece a mensagem que a função não foi definida.

Agora, se eu chegar no console colar e executa o javascript, ele funciona perfeitamente sem erro nenhum.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

### Link contendo o javascript:

http://pastebin.com/dxrHedJD

```
function teste(obj) {
if (obj == "Agonia") {
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:(]'
}else if(obj =="Cool"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[8)]';
}
else if(obj =="Irritado"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:x]';
}
else if(obj =="Feliz"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:)]';
}
else if(obj =="Piscada"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[;)]';
}
else if(obj =="Sorrisao"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:D]';
}
else if(obj =="Surpreso"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:o]';
}
else if(obj =="Lingua"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[:P]';
}
else if(obj =="Doido"){
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText='[/)]';
}
}

document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML='<a href=javascript:teste();><img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/2.gif"> '
+'<a href=javascript:teste("Cool");><img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/1.gif"></a>'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/3.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/4.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/5.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/6.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/7.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/8.gif">'
+'<img src="http://app.e-orkut.com/assets/images/emoticons/9.gif">';
```

Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar de alguma forma.

Comment: Onde estás a colocar esse código na página? Um pastebin com a página toda seria melhor. Estarás a colocar esse código dentro de uma função `onload` ou `.ready(`?

Comment: Até onde eu sei o JavaScript executado na página não pode interagir diretamente com os scripts das extensões, tanto que existe uma API específica só para trocar mensagens. Se você está colocando algum código na página que tenta chamar uma função declarado na extensão isso não vai funcionar. No entanto, você pode injetar o código da sua função na página. Infelizmente eu não tenho o código de como fazer isso, só sei que é possível porque acompanhei o desenvolvimento de uma extensão no trabalho.

Comment: A função está sendo chamada dentro do head.o que eu nao entendo é que se eu executar o script no console do navegador, da pra chamar a função tranquilo. Essa extensão basicamente adiciona um href que a pessoa clica e adiciona um emoticom na texarea

Comment: Exemplificando:  extensao ao iniciar carrega um <a href=funcao();> clique <a/> dentro de uma div do site perto da textarea, quando a pessoa clica insere o emoticom na textarea. Pronto. Como eu disse pelo console funciona, agora pela extensao quando carrega não.

Comment: Poste a parte HTML pra conseguirmos entender melhor como o código funciona.